# Error: ipfs configuration file already exists

Tags: ipfs, decentralized-applications

I already install ipfs via go ipfs. and I don't know why I encounter an error when I want to run "**ipfs init** " in my Terminal. 
could anyone help me to figure out where is the problem?
here is an image of my Terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default IPFS repository path is `~/.ipfs`.
Perhaps you can try to change your default path using:

```
export IPFS_PATH=/path/to/ipfsrepo
```

And then run:

```
ipfs init
```

Also, have you by any chance installed `go-ipfs` from snap?

Comment: it doesn't work. here is the error : **Error: mkdir /path/to/ipfsrepo: no such file or directory** .

Comment: No, I didn't use the snap for installing go-ipfs.

Comment: Try this export IPFS_PATH=/Users/scbas/ipfsrepo

Comment: How did you install ipfs?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have faced this same problem. Because I also installed IPFS Desktop, it initialized some configurations. If you want a fresh start, you delete the initialized IPFS node:

```
> /Users/scbas/.ipfs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not made any directory for IPFS, then using

```
ipfs init
```

will automatically generate a node in your base `Users/Username` directory.

If you want to change the directory, you can create one and then change the path using this command in the terminal according to the directory you created:

```
export IPFS_PATH=/Users/<your system username>/<the name of directory you created>
```

For example, I created an `ipfs-repo` folder for my IPFS node, so I have to run:

```
export IPFS_PATH=/Users/jonah/ipfs-repo
```